# How to package a website with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

We have a standand html website that is in git scm.

How can I use jenkins to package this into a zip for us to easily deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Jenkins job that calls the [git archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) command.

Comment: Thanks. Thats a really simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 1,000,000 ways to skin a cat (or something like that), right?

When I have jenkins pull from git I have it build the workspace exactly as they would appear on the remote server.  This allows for people who are deploying and testing the builds to view the workspace without having to ssh into my servers!  Giving them jenkins access is scary enough! :)  It also allows me to see the expanded workspace as it appears on jenkins (many times without having to ssh into the jenkins box), and reduces troubleshooting time.

Once you workspace is built on jenkins (many times for in a builder job) the workspace is either archived to be used by a downstream job, or it is deployed directly (for simple sites).

Deployments use standard rsync -a --delete

This way, the files get to where they are going and there is a mirror image of the jenkins workspace on the remote server.

You've really gotta evaluate what works best for your deployments...  Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice! That must have been a bit to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a batch or shell script build step (depending on your environment), which calls some zip application to zip your files.